# why does chown have no effect? (13.04)

Tags: 13.04, firefox, root, chown

I am using chown because folders/files I download via Firefox are being saved as being owned by root instead of my own user...

when I used:

```
sudo chown -R -v username:username path/path/path
```

I see logs that show that the relevant files/folders have been changed to be owned by the giver username - yet when I view the files in a file manager they remain 'owned' by root..

does anyone know why this is?

Comment: *"I am using chown because folders/files I download via Firefox are being saved as being owned by root instead of my own user..."* Sounds really suspicious. Instead of dealing with the symptoms, I'd fix the cause instead. How are you running Firefox and how did you install it?

Comment: Apart from what @gertvdijk just said, it will be helpful if you don't show us a "generic" command but the real one you executed.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem on 12.04

Comment: i never received the reply notifications for this thread until today - or i missed them. since i started this thread i have stopped using ubuntu; so am not able to offer direct exploratory assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R -v $USER:$USER path/
```

if you are using -R --recursive then you do not need to add a bunch of paths just make sure that you are in the correct working path. 
the $USER is the varible for the username  that one is using.

Comment: How does your command differ from what the OP wrote?